# Segmentation fault while pushing a vector in another vector in a for loop

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

I am solving the question in gfg in the function when I wrote

```
res.push_back(v)
```

after the if statement it is showing a segmentation fault in the below code

```
vector<vector<int>> stockBuySell(vector<int> A, int n)
{
    vector<vector<int>> res;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        vector<int> v;
        if (A[i] > A[i - 1])
        {
            v.push_back(i - 1);
            while (A[i + 1] > A[i] && i < n - 1)
            {
                i++;
            }
            v.push_back(i);
        }
        res.push_back(v);
    }
    return res;
}
// this is showing segmentation fault
```

but when I am using it inside if condition it is working fine

```
vector<vector<int>> stockBuySell(vector<int> A, int n)
{
    vector<vector<int>> res;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        vector<int> v;
        if (A[i] > A[i - 1])
        {
            v.push_back(i - 1);
            while (A[i + 1] > A[i] && i < n - 1)
            {
                i++;
            }
            v.push_back(i);
            res.push_back(v);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
// this is not showing segmentation fault
```

Comment: `while(A[i+1]>A[i] && i<n-1)`: You access `A[i+1]` **before** checking whether `i` is in bounds?

Comment: Change `A[x]` to `A.at(x)` to check for out of range.  Turn on compiler warnings.  Fix compiler warnings.  It would be helpful if you provided a [mcve], with an emphasis on *minimal*.

Comment: Same problem in the second example. I think you're just getting unlucky and the second code looks like it works. Programing is like that sometimes. Exactly what happens when you go out of bounds is not defined by the C++ Standard, so different things can happen at different times under different conditions.. Some tools add checks, but most don't because checking to make sure the index is in bounds takes time and that time would be an unnecessary penalty on all programs that never go out of bounds.

Comment: How `A[i+1]` can go out of bound for `i=n` but i am checking the condition for i<n-1 so why is this happening